# Battlefield 3: Is there any way to set up a key binding so that when entering a vehicle you go directly to the second seat?

Tags: battlefield-3

This would prevent some awkward moments getting in and out of tanks, like when both driver and gunner get out to repair at the same time.

Edit: To clarify:

1. This question is for PC.
2. I already know that once in the vehicle you can move around between seats with the function keys. This is for avoiding those few seconds lost when both driver and gunner go out to repair and get back in in the wrong order. In those cases, one person needs to get out in order to let the other switch seats, which is an annoying, and a semi-frequent occurrence if you're in the habit of forming stable Driver/Gunner teams. Basically, if I know I want to be in the gunner seat, then why force me to get in the driver seat first?

Comment: What console is this for?

Comment: I feel like this key binding would do more harm than good.

Comment: The order you enter the vehicle isn't the only way to change position.  In the PC version, the function keys will move you to different positions in the vehicle.  For a tank:  F1 to drive, F2 to gun.  If you get in before your driver bud, hit F2.

Comment: @tQuarella Sometimes you simply don't have enough time for that, and while you are moving your finger to F2 someone may take the second place.

Comment: @Emerica. How could option this possibly do harm? I don't want to replace the default one, just create an extra one for when I know I want to be gunner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like to answer with a negative, but I have never seen this option in any Battlefield game going all the way back to 1942, and I've never heard of any option for entering a vehicle in any position other than "first available" in Battlefield 3.

It is of course possible to achieve this, sort of, with an external keyboard macro hack, but as far as an *officially supported, proper built in* way -- no.

Comment: I think it should be reasonable to bind a key using any kind of macro you like, which fires off `E` then `F2` in quick succession. It should work every time.